# Using a Java enum for the datasource on UIPickerview in Objective C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, enums

How would you use a Java enum for the datasource on UIPickerview in Objective C?

I can get the enum as an IOSObjectArray
 but can't find any direction on how to translate it to an NSArray.

This was my last attempt, but I still get this runtime error
([COVisitRequestTypeEnum length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...):

```
NSArray *typeArray = [self arrayFromIOSObjectArray:visitTypeIOSObjectArray];
```

.
.
.

- (NSArray *)arrayFromIOSObjectArray:(IOSObjectArray *)enumArray{
  NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (id element in enumArray){
      [mutableArray addObject:element];
  }
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
  }